# How to get all elements on web page/apk/.ipa

Tags: java, html, parsing, selenium, appium

This is what I am trying to achieve

1. Write a generic parser to parse through an html page (actually , if the user gives an application URL , fetch all pages and retrieve all elements on those pages)and create a list of all elements such as textboxes, buttons, checkboxes, radios, links , dropdowns and so on and dump them to a file as

   ```
   usernameTxtBox: id=xyz
   passwordTxtBox: name=abc
   forgotPasswordLink: linktText=someText
   loginBtn: xapth=//input[@class='xyz']
   ```
2. Write a parser for android apk files , to fetch all pages under that app, generate a list of elements on any particular page , dump to to a file as

   ```
   usernameTxtBox: id=xyz
   passwordTxtBox: id=abc
   forgotPasswordLink: linktText=someText
   loginBtn: xapth=//input[@class='xyz']
   ```
3. Write a praser for ios .ipa files , to fetch all pages under that app, generate a list of elements on any particular page , dump to to a file as

   ```
   usernameTxtBox: accessibilityid=xyz
   passwordTxtBox: accessibilityid=abc
   forgotPasswordLink: text=someText
   loginBtn: xapth=//input[@class='xyz']
   ```

I found "jsoup" html parsing , but how would I achieve this for android and ios apps, I need to generate these elements for automation using selenium with java and for appium with java.

Can anyone please give me the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cases Android & iOS developed in native language,

1. For android most of UI elements are developed in xml in some cases like dynamic views are developed in Java, so here you need to use xml parser instead html.
2. For iOS also you need to use xml parser. Appium give you xml output when you get page source.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way , where in i can first get all the xml for all pages in android/ios without calling getPageSource()?